# Vue and axios make request and display result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to set up a vue app that makes a request to a backend and then displays the result on the page. I cooked up this example

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        message: '{}'
    },
    el: '.login-app',
});

Vue.component('message-section', {
    template: '<div>Message Section</div>'
});

Vue.component('login-component', {
    template: '<div><button v-on:click="login(\'mike@fake.com\', \'passwd\')">Login</button></div>',
    methods: {
        login: function (username, password) {
            axios.post("http://192.168.1.10:8080/login", {username: username, password: password})
                .then(response => {this.message = response.data})
        }
    }
});
```

and an index like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vue Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-app">
      {{ message }}
      <message-section></message-section>
      <login-component></login-component>
    </div>
    <script src="/static/testvue.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The idea being a simple app that should send a username/password and get back something like "success" or whatever that it can display. But I am completely unfamiliar with vue and javascript so I am getting stuck. I am not sure how to make the response show up anywhere. I have a {{ message }} in there but it doesn't do anything. All I see is the {} from the "message" attribute of the Vue object getting rendered in I guess. And those user/pass is hard coded... I am not sure how to make it work with a form field.

I can see the data getting sent to the backend though so I know that's working...

Additionally, how can you structure a Vue project so it's broken into multiple "modules" or whatever?

Edit:

If I change it so there's only one component like so:

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        message: '{}'
    },
    el: '.login-app',
    methods: {
        login: function (username, password) {
            axios.post("http://192.168.91.30:8080/login", {username: username, password: password})
                .then(response => {this.message = response.data})
        }
    }

})
```

and

```
<div class="login-app">
  {{ message }}
  <button v-on:click="login(\'mike@fake.com\', \'passwd\')">Login</button>
</div>
```

Then nothing renders at all...  This should have put them inside the same container or whatever, right?

Comment: The core issue here is `message` is a data property declared in your root Vue, but you are attempting to set it from a component that doesn't have direct access to it. Typically, if you want to change the value from a child component, you will need to $emit the value to the parent.

Comment: I have no idea what that means... but I edited my question a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your edited code working.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  data: {
    message: '{}'
  },
  el: '#login-app',
  methods: {
    login: function(username, password) {
      axios.post("https://httpbin.org/post", {username, password})
        .then(response => this.message = response.data.json)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="login-app">
  {{ message }}
  <button v-on:click="login('mike@fake.com', 'passwd')">Login</button>
</div>
```

Here it is working from a component.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component('login-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button v-on:click="login('mike@fake.com', 'passwd')">Login</button>
    </div>`,
  methods: {
    login: function(username, password) {
      axios.post("https://httpbin.org/post", {username, password})
        .then(response => this.$emit('login-success', response.data.json))
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  data: {
    message: '{}'
  },
  el: '#login-app',
  methods: {
    onSuccess(message) { this.message = message }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="login-app">
  {{ message }}
  <login-component @login-success="onSuccess"></login-component>
</div>
```

In this second example, note that `message` is a data property of the *parent*; the root Vue. The `login-component` **does not have direct access** to `message`. That being the case, if the ajax call is made in the *component*, in order to set `message` the value has to be emitted from the component. The code does that by emitting the custom event, `login-success` with the success value passed as a parameter. The parent listens for that event with the following syntax:

```
<login-component @login-success="onSuccess"></login-component>
```

Comment: In the first example, all you seem to have changed from my "edited" thing is changing a .login-app to #login-app and also adding a .json to the response.data. What's the difference between the dot and the hash?

Comment: @MichaelB You don't want to create a Vue on a class because there could be more than one element with that class. It's just a bad practice. `#login-app` is a CSS selector that chooses an element with the *id* of `login-app`. You can safely ignore my changes to the ajax call; those are only because there is no way to make a call to *your* server, so I updated the call to use a generic site that handles POSTs.

Comment: So, in the second case, you're telling the parent to listen for an event called @login-success and when it hears that, run its own onSuccess method. Then you "emit" the login-success event from the child and the argument of whatever the ajax thing returned and they just get wired together.

Comment: @MichaelB You got it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your component `login-component` doesn't have access to the `message` property, which belongs to the root Vue app.

One way to fix this is simply put the `message` to the component instead:

```
Vue.component('login-component', {
  template: '<div><button v-on:click="login(\'mike@fake.com\', \'passwd\')">Login</button></div>',
  data() { 
    return { message: '' }
  },
  methods: {
    login: function (username, password) {
      axios.post("http://192.168.1.10:8080/login", {username: username, password: password})
        .then(response => {this.message = response.data})
      }
    }
});
```

But if `message` is not a property that you `login-component` to have solely access to, you may have to consider `Vuex` or emitting custom events ([this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Events) and [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)).